# Spark Scala GroupBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by

i've following dataset :

```
col1_id,    col2_id,       type

1           t1_1                t1 
1           t1_2                t1
2           t2_2                t2
```

`col1_id & col2_id` have one to many relationship i.e. multiple `col2_id` can have same `col1_id` value
type (eg. `t1`) is derived from `col2_id`

Objective is to find number of `col1_id` having a type (i.e. `t1`, `t2` etc)

Here is what i'm doing currently,

```
val df1 = df.select($"col1_id", $"type").groupBy($"col1_id", $"type").count()
df1.drop($"count").groupBy($"type").show()
```

this works fine .. however i'm wondering if there might be a better way to accomplish this.
Pls let me know.

Comment: I don't think your example works "fine", it does not even compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you mention `col2_id`, it does not play a role here?

I expect what you want to do is to count the distinct `col1_id` values per type? If yes, then do :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct

df
  .groupBy($"type")
  .agg(
    countDistinct($"col1_id")
  )
  .show()
```